# Using roles to manage user's AWS account

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, credentials

I want to set up a web service which will manage few resources on a user's behalf (on his own AWS account).

So basically, after a user logs in, he will provide my service with proper permission to access his account. I've noticed similar services (https://www.dashbird.io/), which instruct you on how to create a proper role, but I'm not sure on how to actually use the role. How to login on his behalf (there is no token nor password).

I'm using node.js, but other examples will help as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application will need valid credentials to access resources in your customer's AWS Account. Theses credentials can be provided in various ways, but they would most probably be either:

- Credentials for an **IAM User** in your customer's account, or
- An **IAM Role** in your customer's account, which they have configured to allow you to assume

**IAM User**

This is the simplest method. Your customer would create an **IAM User** and provide it with appropriate permissions. They would then supply your application with the Access Key and Secret Key associated with the User.

Your application would use those credentials when establishing a session with AWS services.

**IAM Role**

Your customer would create an **IAM Role** and provide it with appropriate permissions. Unlike an IAM User, an IAM Role does not have credentials. Rather, **an AWS User *assumes* a Role**. They are then provided with temporary credentials that can be used to use AWS services in that account.

Think of it like a Fire Warden -- if there is a fire in an office building, somebody temporarily *assumes the role* of Fire Warden, telling people what to do. When there's a fire, they have authority because they assumed the role. But when there's no fire, they have no authority to tell you what to do.

The customer would need to configure the Role to **trust** your Account, or a User in your account. They will then give you the ARN (Amazon Resource Name) of the Role. Your application then uses an IAM User in your own Account to call `AssumeRole()`. If that IAM User (or your whole account) is trusted, then you will receive back credentials for accessing your customer's account.

See:

- [Creating a Role to Delegate Permissions to an IAM User](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-user.html)
- [AssumeRole](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html)

Comment: So if I understand correctly: my customer creates a role to trust MY account, and then any user in my account can use AssumeRole to gain temporary credentials and manage resources?

Comment: Correct. They can either trust your ROOT, which means your whole account, or they can trust a specific User within your account. If they wish to revoke access, they can just delete the Role or modify the Trust policy. They will need to supply you with the ARN (Amazon Resource Name) of the Role so that you can assume it.